# Can VLC Player save an `.mpg` file?

Tags: vlc-media-player, file-format

I have a short family video on DVD. I've successfully used VLC player to save it as a file, but it has a file extension of `.ps`.

I want to put it in a Picasa album, but Picasa only recognizes videos with the following file extensions: `.avi`, `.mpg`, `.asf`, `.wmv`.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Open the video
- Choose Media > Convert/Save
- Add the same file and click Convert/Save button
- Click the wrench icon for more options
- Select an encapsulation of MPEG-TS, a video codec of MPEG-4, and unchecked the audio under that codec's section (there is none in this video).
- Click "Browse" and supply a location and filename (with no extension)
- Click "Start"

Regardless of the encoding options, the file extension is still `.ps`.

How can I save as `.mpg`?

Comment: Update: following these instructions, I've gotten an `.mp4` file which VLC player can play, and Quicktime and Picasa can open but play as just a black screen. http://www.wikihow.com/Rip-a-DVD-Using-VLC-Media-Player

Answer (score 5):

- Go to the Media menu and choose Convert/Save. Click on the Disc tab.
- Here you can adjust the Starting Position and rip only specific titles or chapters.
- Enter file name making sure to end with .mpg, and start ripping.
- Click Save.

Comment: I can give it a filename ending in .mpg, but it doesn't seem to be one; Quicktime can't open it and Picasa doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Hmm, what version of VLC do you have?

Comment: VLC media player 2.0.6 Twoflower

Comment: Can't see why this wouldn't work then...

Answer (score 2):

In the context of video, the `.ps` file extension [normally represents an MPEG Program Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_PS), which is the same file type represented by the `.mpg` or `.mpeg` extensions. You should be able to simply rename the files.

Since you've selected MPEG TS (Transport Stream, which is really more useful for broadcast than sitting on a file on your computer) as the container, VLC *might* be doing something silly... but if it *was* a transport stream, I'd have thought that it would use the `.ts` file extension. So most likely, you can simply rename the files you already have.